# Getting rotation values ​of another object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera, it is attached to the capsule, and rotates independently of it.

But I need the capsule to rotate along the Y axis following the camera. How to get the Y-axis rotation values ​​of the camera? Tried through **transform.rotation.y**. But it gives an error.

Comment: Why do you want the _capsule_ to follow the camera? Rotating or otherwise?

Comment: Try add the camera as a child of your capsule object and try to rotate only the capsule.

Comment: I already did this, the problem is that when tilted up, the capsule also tilts, but I need that when tilting vertically, the capsule was motionless, and when turning horizontally, it followed the camera.

Answer (score 0):

[`Transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) returns a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) (see also [Wikipedia - Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)) - it has not 3 but **4** components `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`**!

=> Unless you know exactly what you are doing - which is almost never the case ^^ - you do never want to touch any of its components directly.

Unfortunately also the [`Transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) are not really reliable for your use case.

---

So what I would do is rely on `Vector3` instead.

```
// take camera's forward vector
private forward = yourCamera.transform.forward;
// erase the Y axis => vector is now only on the XZ plane rotating around Y
forward.y = 0;

// rotate the capsule so its forward vector aligns with "forward"
yourCapsule.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward);
// could also do
//yourCapsule.transform.forward = forward;
```

see also [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)